# Where is tabPositions instanced when I use TabRow with Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is source code of fun `TabRow`.

There is a paramter named  `indicator` which need to be passed when invoked, and Android give a default implementation  `@Composable { tabPositions -> TabRowDefaults.Indicator( Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex])) }`

But I don't know where the paramter `tabPositions` is instanced, could you tell me?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    indicator: @Composable (tabPositions: List<TabPosition>) -> Unit = @Composable { tabPositions ->
        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
            Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex])
        )
    },
    divider: @Composable () -> Unit = @Composable {
        TabRowDefaults.Divider()
    },
    tabs: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier.selectableGroup(),
        color = backgroundColor,
        contentColor = contentColor
    ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indicator` parameter is a lambda that you provide and the code behind TabRow will call it and pass in the tabPositions. Just search the source code for `indicator(`:

[TabRow](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/material/TabRow.kt;l=67?q=TabRow&sq=)

You'll find that it gets called here:

```kotlin
subcompose(TabSlots.Indicator) {
                    indicator(tabPositions)
                }.fastForEach {
                    it.measure(Constraints.fixed(tabRowWidth, tabRowHeight)).placeRelative(0, 0)
                }
```